# load mongodb with nested collections in qlikview

Tags: xml, json, mongodb, qlikview

I have to connect to a mongo db to load a lot of filtered datas in qlikview. Qlikview does not know json, but he knows ODBC, xml, csv...
I don't use REST (massive data and rest are incompatible due to the size of the result).
I tried QVSource with their mongodb connector, but the nested collections are given in json.
This is an example :
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0LEAf.png]
I found a way to convert json to xml with a macro in qlikview, but it's laborious. The json is not perfect, then the conversion failed. So I'm searching a better solution.
I Tried an ODBC connector (simba), but the nested collections are converted to columns. (I tested 2 softwares, so the ODBC connector do this error). In this example, anna doa has 2 emails addresses, so I have 1 column per email, not 2 rows. I'd like to have 2 rows.
I asked a trial license for an other ODBC connector (easysoft), and I tried it. Same result.

So, is there an other solution ?

Comment: Have you tried this one: http://www.unityjdbc.com/mongojdbc/mongo_jdbc.php

Comment: I just tried unity, it's better for simples sub-documents, but same problem for arrays of sub-documents. I get json and I get $oid and $date. It's not safe. Any other idea ?

Comment: Can you not address email.0, email.1 etc.?

Comment: Perhaps, but I can not know in advance how many columns there will be. So, it gets complicated. Moreover , the problem of "$oid " and "$date " remains. I found an other solution : export mongodb collections to csv files, because Qlikview can import csv files. But this is not efficient.

Comment: I just added some additional docs to QVSource regarding MongoDB nested array support - http://wiki.qvsource.com/MongoDB-Connector-For-QlikView.ashx?NoRedirect=1#Extracting_Arrays_1 - I believe in your example if you enter '_id' for the sub document key path and 'emails' for the sub document path you will get 1 row per email (i.e. 3 rows in the above) but the problem then will be accessing futher arrays under each email.